# Guava EventBus: What does it mean to listen to event supertypes (such as EventObject or Object)?

Tags: java, guava

In the [Google Guava EventBusExplained](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/EventBusExplained) page, I don't understand when they say the following:

> To listen for a common event supertype (such as EventObject or
>   Object)... 
>   ...in traditional Java events: not easy. 
>   
> ...with EventBus:
>   events are automatically dispatched to listeners of any supertype,
>   allowing listeners for interface types or "wildcard listeners" for
>   Object.

1. What does it mean to listen for a common event supertype?
2. When they mention EventObject , are they talking about java.util.EventObject?
3. What does it mean to allow "listeners for interface types or "wildcard listeners" for Object"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has to do with the limitations of method-overloading and interfaces that Guava's `EventBus` class can overcome.

For interfaces, consider the following scenario:

I have the same code that gets invoked for multiple forms of input. For example, a listener that listens to mouse events, key events, and focus events, but all methods do the same thing: repaint the source. This would mean that my code would look like this:

```
public class BunchOfListeners implements MouseListener, KeyListener, FocusListener {

    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
        doSomething(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
        doSomething(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        doSomething(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        doSomething(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        doSomething(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        doSomething(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        doSomething(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        doSomething(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        doSomething(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        doSomething(e);
    }

    public void doSomething(EventObject e) {
        ((Component) e.getSource()).repaint();
    }
}
```

Notice how ugly this is? There are 10 different methods for this, when ultimately the only thing we care about is getting the source off the event (which is specified by `EventObject`, by the way, which is why they used that in their example) and calling `repaint` on it.

With Guava's `EventBus`, this gets super, super simple. All I need in my <strike>`GuavaIsAwesome`</strike> `ComponentRepainter` class is one method:

```
public class ComponentRepainter {

    @Subscribe
    public void doSomething(EventObject e) {
        ((Component) e.getSource()).repaint();
    }
}
```

When you register this with an `EventBus` and later fire, say, a `MouseEvent` on it:

```
EventBus eventBus = ... ;
eventBus.register(new ComponentRepainter());
```

And later:

```
MouseEvent e = ... ;
eventBus.post(e);
```

This will call the `doSomething` method on `ComponentRepainter` because it will not only fire the event to `@Subscribe` methods with `MouseEvent` for the parameter, but also to any methods that have a parameter that is *assignable* from `MouseEvent`. In other words, because `MouseEvent` extends `EventObject`, Guava's `EventBus` will pass it to anything that accepts `EventObject`. If we made `doSomething` accept `Object`, then we can get *every* event that's posted to the `EventBus`, making it a sort of global listener (because *everything* in Java extends `Object`).

The same thing applies to interfaces as well. If you pass a concrete implementation to `EventBus` of some interface, then `@Subscribe` methods that use the interface (as opposed to the concrete type) will be called. It's much more flexible, and overcomes the "10 useless methods" approach.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have two event sources: one firing events of type `FooEvent`, and one firing events of type `BarEvent`. Suppose `FooEvent` and `BarEvent` extend a common superclass (or implement a common interface) `MyEvent`.

With EventBus, you can listen to events of type `MyEvent`, and you'll be notified of `FooEvent`s and `BarEvent`s, because they both extend this common supertype `MyEvent`.

If you listen for events of type `java.lang.Object`, then you will be notified of every event, since every class in Java extends Object. That would be a wildcard listener: it listens at everything.